# Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build my code and this is what I am getting:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':MyPlugin:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /home/kristyna/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/1ad45cefc0a573e6c029ad0130df4c51/transformed/jetified-commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

It has been a while since I have opened this project and now all the sudden this is happening.

I have tried `./gradlew clean` and `./gradlew --stop`. That didn't help. Next on my list is to delete `~/.gradle/caches` but I would rather avoid this step. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have deleted `~/.gradle/caches`, it did not help either.

EDIT2: It happened with a different project now, again the code has not changed. This makes me believe it is something in my environment. I have re-downloaded 7.5 gradle and it is still not working. But it works if I change the project to use gradle 8.
Why is it happening all of the sudden?

Answer (score 1):

For any one who comes across the issue, for me it was that I was running with the wrong Java home and with Java 21 instead of 17 from the command line.

In Android Studio you can find this setting in `Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Build Tools/Gradle/Gradle JDK`. It should be set to the one that Android Studio has inbuilt.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I tried to switch to 17 and 11 with the same result

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

If you are working with flutter on vscode without android studio, I solved this issue by downgrading my Java version from the latest jdk 21 to jdk 17.

- Install a later jdk version
- update your environmental variables

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I tried to switch to 17 and 11 with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, tried the latest Java 17 and it didn't work either, in the end I had to downgrade the package I was using.  I was using different package:

`commons-codec:commons-codec:1.16.0` instead `of commons-codec:commons-codec:1.16.1`

So maybe try `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0` instead of `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0` for the time being.

Just tried adding `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0` to my app and got the same issue you reported, changing it to `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0` worked.

Again, not ideal, but no reported CVEs on this lower package at least.

Update:
The exact implementation of a fix depends on how you manage dependencies.  However, to provide an example for the build.gradle file, this would be to replace:
`org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0`
with:
`org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0`
inside build.gradle `dependancies` section i.e.

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0'
}
```

instead of:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'
}
```