Flutter Firebase App unable to build (Android)
I've been attempting to construct this project, but I keep running into this issue.
D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

Also:
Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /home/john/Music/flutter_application/build/image_picker_android/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_dir/debug.
     > Error while dexing.

After a series of debugging sessions and checking for possible solutions to the build issue, I couldn't find any.
I am running it with:
Flutter 3.24.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Java version: openjdk 21.0.4 2024-07-16
Gradle version 8.5
Firebase version 13.15.2

My "build.gradle":
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId = "com.example.flutter_application"
    // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
    // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode = flutter.versionCode
    versionName = flutter.versionName
    multiDexEnabled true

}

Please, I need help to solve this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587376/cannot-invoke-string-length-because-parameter1-is-null

Did you use appcompat library and compile with sdk 34？
If so，just delete appcompat lib and use sdk 33
